# Customized Monthly View to show number Kendo scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

How can I customize the Kendo scheduler's month view, so that it shows the count of events on each cell?

Is there anyway to navigate through each cell of the month view programmatically?

Any hint or direction is greatly appreciated.

All I need is to achieve the following effect: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part of this question is to navigate through all the cells in month view. The following code does the job:

```
        var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
        var view = scheduler.view();
        var slots = view.table.find("td[role='gridcell']");
        slots.each(function () { 
             var slot = scheduler.slotByElement(this);  
             //do whatever you want here with the slot variable 
         }
```

Hope it helps.